# В очереди проверок есть уведомление, но очередь пуста

Tags: дефект

Весит уведомление в "Запоздалые ответы", но при заходе пишет, что очередь пуста. 
Я пробовал перезагружать страницу (ctrl+F5), перезапускать браузер, отключать расширения.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

[image: скриншот]